# using python sum directly on an equation?

Tags: python, math

```
import math

(2*math.sqrt(2)/9801)*math.fsum((math.factorial(4*k)(1103+26390*k))/(math.factorial(k)**4396**4*k) for k in range(1,100))
```

The above equation should what is to the right of the following the image resulting in 1/pie [here](http://www.economist.com/blogs/babbage/2014/02/neurology?fsrc=scn/fb/wl/bl/beautyandthegeek)

However, I am getting an "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

I've looked on stackoverflow and it seems that they turn each equation to a set and then use the sum function. Is it possible to use it as show above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just have a simple error - and I should note, one that gets me all the time. You can't multiply with parentheses, e.g., (2x)(y<sup>2</sup>) = 2xy<sup>2</sup>. That's what's giving you the `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`. It should be

```
(2*math.sqrt(2)/9801)*math.fsum((math.factorial(4*k)*(1103+26390*k))/(math.factorial(k)**4396**4*k) for k in range(1,100))
```

All you're missing is `*` between `(math.factorial(4*k)` and `(1103+26390*k))`.

However, this is a behemoth of an evaluation. I got a `MemoryError` trying to run it. My guess is that you'll need some kind of specialty number-chugging library to run something like this (or at least to somehow allow python to use up more than the default amount of memory). Unfortunately, I have no experience with either.

**Edit**: Definitely look into NumPy/SciPy. But I'm running 32-bit python. So if you're on 64-bit, it's possible you won't have a problem - don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here

```
math.factorial(4*k)(1103+26390*k)
```

That evaluates `math.factorial(4 * k)` and then tries to call it with the argument `1103 + 26390 * k`.

To avoid similar errors, it's helpful to include spaces around operators and break complicated operations into several lines of code. That will also make it easier to debug, as it will be more clear where the error is happening (here your question about `sum` is a red herring).